# Javascript dataTransfer.setData is adding text to Clipboard in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, events

I have a web page that has draggable UI elements. When using Internet Explorer, whenever I drag any UI element, some text gets added to the clipboard. When using Chrome this doesn't happen.

The text that is added is needed for other operations, but I don't want it to be added in the clipboard, so the behavior I have in Chrome is the one I want.

I did some troubleshooting and I was able to identify the code where this happens, bellow is a snippet of code where this can be replicated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<script>
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('TEXT', 'this text is added to clipboard');
}
</script>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
 <div>
   <p id="me" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);" draggable="true">Drag me</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, if you run the snippet of code in Internet Explorer, if you drag the "Drag me" element, you will notice that some text gets added in the Clipboard, so next time you CTRL+V that text will be pasted.

Did anyone ever faced this problem? Is there a way for me to have the same behavior on both browsers? Or I will have to change my implementation?

Comment: Just for the sake of interest: Why did you chose to use the DataTransfer API in the first place? The method DataTransfer.setData is not supported in IE11: [caniuse DataTransfer.setData](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_datatransfer_setdata)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior in IE11 is a bit weird. I tested your snippet with jsbin.com and started with commenting out

```
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
```

The result was I was able to drag the element `#me` and no content was added into the clipboard via IE11.

Additionally I successfully retrieved the value of `'TEXT'` via the `DataTransfer` api.

I cannot explain why the initial behavior described above appears in IE11.

Comment: When I remove the effectAllowed call (as suggested) I still have the same issue. It was the only thing you did?

Comment: No, took a look into caniuse.com. Please refer to the comment below your opening post 